# Why is sails-mysql causing errors with passport-local?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sails.js, passport-local, passport.js

I'm working on a Sails application, all while teaching myself about Sails and Node. I am following [this tutorial](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/), and though I had to make a few changes here and there due to bcrypt's windows requirements being absolutely insane, I got the bulk of it working. My issue seems to be in the tutorials `config/passport.js` file. I've ended up modifying the contents a bit as I was going through debug.

The exact error is

```
C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\sails-mysql\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Parser.js:77
        throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:344:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:134:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:595:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:151:12)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:237:15)
    at ServerResponse.res.send (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:139:21)
    at C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\api\controllers\AuthController.js:22:30
    at C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\sails-auth\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:51:48
    at pass (C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\sails-auth\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:287:14)
    at Authenticator.serializeUser (C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\sails-auth\node_modules\passport\lib\authenticator.js:289:5)
    at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\sails-auth\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:50:29)
    at C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\api\controllers\AuthController.js:21:17
    at Strategy.strategy.success (C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\passport\lib\middleware\authenticate.js:194:18)
    at verified (C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\node_modules\passport-local\lib\strategy.js:83:10)
    at C:\Users\Jhecht\Desktop\sails\students\config\passport.js:28:5
    at returnResults (C:\Users\Jhecht\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\sails\node_modules\waterline\lib\waterline\query\finders\basic.js:180:9)
Program exited with code 1
```

config/passport.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user.user_id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    Users.findOne({
        user_id: id
    }, function (err, user) {
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField: 'user_email',
        passwordField: 'user_password'
    },
    function (email, password, done) {
        Users.findOne({
            user_email: email
        }, function (err, user) {
            if (err) {
                return done(err);
            }
            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Email not found, are you sure you registered?'
                });
            }

            if (bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.user_password)) { //Changed from tutorial to see if the error was coming from the async function
                console.info("User Found, Hashes are equal."); //Me finding errors
                done(null, user, {
                    message: 'Login Successful'
                });
                //Removing this line I don't get the error in the console and the server doesn't reset, but without it the authentication doesn't work
            }
        });
    }
));
```

I unfortunately do not know enough about Sails/Node to figure out what exactly is going on. The error appears to be thrown by the sails-mysql adapter, but *only* if the `done()` function is called. Without the `done()` call, however, I can't get Passport to authorize the user.

Comment: Have you read [this comment](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/#comment-2101000934) on the tutorial page? Can you post your `AuthController.js` as well? The line numbers in the error trace can give some hint where things are going wrong.

Comment: I feel like an idiot for not noticing that comment sooner. Just when you think you aren't a total noob anymore. Now my problem is that everything works - no errors, but the user is never actually logged in (e.g. calling `req.isAuthenticated()` always returns false, even if I just logged in. The login page just gives me a blank object. Funsies. If you'd like you can post your comment as an answer and I will accept it since it answered my problem.

Comment: It happens to all of us. =) And debugging isn't always that straightforward, with asynchronous calls and stuff.

Comment: I think you have an unhandled case: user is found in database, but given password doesn't match the one in the database. That is: `if (bcrypt.compareSync(...)) { ... } else { return done(null, false, { message: 'Wrong username/password combination'}); }`.

Comment: you were correct, I was. In my frustrations I deleted it. Even with it all I'm getting is `{}` after a login attempt (successful or not);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial contains an error in `AuthController.js`, missing a `return` in the `login()` function as mentioned in [this comment](http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/#comment-2101000934). The `req.logIn()` part should be:

```
req.logIn(user, function(err) {
    if (err) return res.send(err);
    return res.send({
        message: info.message,
        user: user
    });
});
```